# socket io rooms do not get any data from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to create chat rooms for my react native and i write that code for my react native app:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
    socket.emit("new-user", "hello world");
    socket.on("room1", (data) => {
      socket.on("user-connected", (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

And here is the server code:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("made socket connection", socket.id);

  socket.on("new-user", (data) => {
    socket.join("room1");
    socket.to("room1").broadcast.emit("user-connected", data);
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

The connection was established but the chat "room1" or "user-connected" do not receive any data from server. How can i listen the chat romm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server code change

```
socket.to("room1").broadcast.emit("user-connected", data);
```

to

```
socket.to("room1").emit("user-connected", data);
```

And in your client code you don't need extra `socket.on("room1")`. So your final client code will be like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
socket.emit("new-user", "hello world");
  socket.on("user-connected", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
return () => {
  socket.disconnect();
};
}, []);
```

Comment: But i do not understand how the client listen the specific room.

Comment: Client doesn't need to listen specific room.Because when you fired 'user-connected' event from server it will be send to clients that connected to 'room1'.

Comment: You are connecting client to 'room1' when a client fire 'new-user' event. `socket.on("new-user", (data) => {
    socket.join("room1");
  });`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
    socket.emit("new-user", "hello world");
    socket.on("user-connected", (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

You don't have to listen to a specific room on the front end. Since each socket automatically joins a room identified by its id. The server knows which user is in which room.

You can read more about it in [this specific section](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/index.html#socket-join-room) of socket io documentation.